# Sequelize query (findAll where include) many to many relations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to select all **posts** with a specific **tag**, but have loaded all tags in these posts, how do I access relationship columns?

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  limit: limit ? limit : 50,
  offset: offset ? offset : 0,
  order: [[sort ? sort : 'createdAt', order ? order : 'DESC']],

  where: {
    owner_id: req.userId,
  },

  include: [
    {
      association: 'tags',
      through: { attributes: [] },
    },
  ],
});
```

Posts e Tags are relation many to many with a through table.

I thought of something like that:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  limit: limit ? limit : 50,
  offset: offset ? offset : 0,
  order: [[sort ? sort : 'createdAt', order ? order : 'DESC']],

  where: {
    owner_id: req.userId,
  },

  include: [
    {
      association: 'tags',
      through: { attributes: [] },
      where: {
        name: { [Op.ilike]: my_tag_for_search },
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

but return the only tag, and I need all tags of the post that have this specific tag.

Comment: Right now the easiest way is to do in 3 parts.
First find all tag ids matching the tag search query.  
Then find the post id in the through table having those found tag id.
Then make a findAll query in Post including the tags model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `separate` option in the `include`, which will query the associated models separately instead of joining them. Here is the updated query:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  limit: limit ? limit : 50,
  offset: offset ? offset : 0,
  order: [[sort ? sort : "createdAt", order ? order : "DESC"]],
  where: {
    owner_id: req.userId,
  },
  include: [
    {
      association: "tags",
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      },
      where: {
        name: {
          [Op.ilike]: my_tag_for_search,
        },
      },
      separate: true, // this is the key option
    },
  ],
});
```